# Can I receive a JavaScript Object on an API WITHOUT a Corresponding C# Object?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API 2 controller. I am sending a JavaScript Object from the client in a call:

```
myObject = {propertyOne: 'Hi', propertyTwo: 'Bye'}
```

Do I HAVE to make a class with those properties in C# to receive the object as an argument to the Web API controller?

```
    public void controllerMethod(myObject object)
    {

    }
```

Is there away to AVOID making an object that will only be used to receive data? If so, how?

Comment: have you tried public void controllerMethod(string propertyOne, string propertyTwo)

Comment: No, I am sure that would work though. I just wanted to see what the consensus was on this.

Comment: no difference I would say. Its your preference, if are passing the object back and forth then yes, if not I see no reason in creating an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below would work, but not recommended.

```
public void controllerMethod(dynamic myObject)
    {

    }
```

Among a number of benefits, it's a positive security benefit to create an object and bind it so that you can't get extra properties posted in from an attacker that are not intended to be there.

Comment: Thank you - so making an object is essentially good practice?